# How to make Music (Noise) remember the volume value

Tags: music

So each time I launch Noise i have to go to the volume control to lower its sound volume cause it's at 100% on default and I prefer to have it lower. Is there a way to make Noise default to a particular volume value or do I have to do this every time?

Answer (score 0):

Noise is designed to use the system volume settings (just like Audience/Videos app). I guess having two different controls for volume (system versus in-app) is considered confusing. I have met people confused about volume on their own (Windows) machine, so I get that it can be seen as a problem.